# How to check if user exists before inscription with devise rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I m using devise for registration user, but my way it is a little diffrente, how ?

the user can sign up juste when another user give him his ID 
so the new user need to verifie the ID before continue 
how can i do it  ?

Comment: It sounds like a `find_or_create_by`?

Comment: can you give me a detailed explanation ?

Comment: Are the users Id obfuscated ? Because then it is useless: everyone can guess any other user ID and register. Will some relationship between the new user and the user who provided the ID exists after registration (like a "friendship")  ? What you can do is generate a random token and associate it with every user. This token can be passed and checked before a new user is registered. A user can send a registration link with this token attached. Please give more details about security level.

Comment: no no it is not that, yes there is a relation between the new user and the one giving the ID, what I want to do is to check the existence of the user who gave ID, not for me but for the new user who wants to register ....
example ...
enter the ID: 152498658 ....
there is not a user who has this ID
...or ...
the user's name is automatically displayed

Comment: Just let every user sign up, provide a field named verifier_id, when user click on signup button then in User.rb file add before_save call back and verify if user's provided id matches your given id, if yes then create user otherwise show error message

Answer (score 0):

If you are using devise,then a better approach is to use the devise_invitable gem,with this,you can send invitations to users directly to their mailbox and also have access to who invited a particular user and lots of other stuffs.